# A static electron and a radiating electron

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

Let us consider an electron A, which is at rest in one frame of reference and another electron B which is accelerating in that frame of reference. Now the fields due to electron B are time varying . Suppose we have a mechanism by which we can always ensure that electron
A always remains at rest in frame A. Now the force exerted by electron B on electron A would be equal to the charge of electron times the electric field E at the place the electron is located . As such the force exerted on electron A is time varying as well as depending on its distance from electron B . Now the force exerted by electron A on B ,by newton's third law of motion ,should be equal in magnitude and hence should also depend on time not only on distance as it happens in case of coulomb's force.  But electron A can only exert coulombian force . Will this violate third law of motion ?

Comment: Please, could you explain *"Suppose we have a mechanism by which we can always ensure that electron A always remains at rest in frame A."* ? What do you mean by **at rest** here ? and what is the presumed mechanism involved ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You call one of your electrons "radiating", and there is certainly radiation involved. The electrons do not act at each other directly, but through electromagnetic field, so this is not a two-body case of the third law of motion.

Comment: Could you elaborate ??

Comment: @Agnivesh Singh: you may look, say, at http://web.hep.uiuc.edu/home/serrede/P436/Lecture_Notes/P436_Lect_02.pdf

Comment: @akhtmeteli : I was actually intending to post another question about the meaning of a field carrying momentum but still then could you tell me whether the field due to electron A would be time varying ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: Actually, I am not sure. The conditions you impose are somewhat artificial. On the one hand, "we have a mechanism by which we can always ensure that electron A always remains at rest in frame A." If this is so, the electron should not disturb the field of electron B, so the field due to electron A should be static. However. the radiated field of electron B can reflect from / refract in the above mechanism. You decide if you want to call such reflected/refracted field "due to electron A" or not.

Comment: Ok , instead of two electrons let's make it two charged spherical balls . Now , if the force due to ball B on ball A is time varying then so should be the force on ball B due to ball A , if we can strongly hold ball A or let's say fix it to a clamp. But at the same time as we can see Ball A is static . And there's no reason to take reflected fields into consideration ..I am solely speaking about the fields of only these two ..nothing else..

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: I don't quite see how this can change anything. And I don't understand why we should not take reflected fields into account. Mind you, I am not trying to say that the balls will act on each other with equal and opposite forces, as in the third law of motion, I am just trying to say that the difference is due to momentum carried by the field.

Comment: Yes and I am just trying to  be confirmed about the field created by the static particle (ball )...

Comment: Hope you could provide an answer with surety and with reasons..

Comment: @Agnivesh Singh: I cannot offer much "surety" using your assumptions for the reason given above: I have problems with the "mechanism by which we can always ensure that electron A always remains at rest in frame A." So I suggest that we change the assumptions. Let us assume that A is not an electron, but a very heavy particle, so the forces due to electron B do not change the position of A appreciably. Then the field due to A will be static indeed. Note, however, that the force acting on B will vary in time due to B's motion (the field due to A is the Coulomb field, which is not homogeneous).

Comment: Wouldn't the static field of A violate newton's third law ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: I don't think so. Again, you need to decide to which bodies you are going to apply the third law. The third law is indeed looks violated if you apply it to A and B in your situation, but the violation can be explained by the field momentum - A and B interact via the field, rather than directly. You can apply the law, say, to A and electromagnetic field or to B and electromagnetic field.

Comment: @Akhmetelli : But I guess we need newton's third law to hold good in order to have momentum conserved ...or would you resort to a sophisticated proof of it by some Noether's theorem ( I have heard about it only ..don't understand it )

Comment: Could you explain the whole idea of a field carrying momentum ???

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: Sorry, I am not going to prove momentum conservation in classical electrodynamics. As for field carrying momentum, it is the total momentum of A, B, and field that is conserved, not that of A and B.  The field momentum can be observed as radiation pressure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure ). I am out of this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Any charge placed in the vicinity of another charge will always respond to the electric field created around it. In this case the charge A is experiencing a force due to the charge B by responding to B's electric field and vise versa. So the force on A is time varying. in the same manner the charge B will experience a force due charge A by responding the electric field created by A at position of charge B which is also time varying. hence Newton's law is not violated in this case.